# Existence of solution of linear differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

I am being told this fact a lot recently:

> $\text{Claim}$: Let $A:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow Mat_n(\mathbb{R})$ be a matrix valued function with smooth coefficients. Then for any $c\in \mathbb{R}$, there exists a unique differentiable vector valued function $y:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $y(0)=c$ and $\dot{y}=Ay$.

I would like to see a proof of this fact. I looked up wiki and saw that existence of *local* solutions is guaranteed by picard's theorem (but the claim of this post guarantees global existence of solutions). I didn't go through the details of the proof of picard's theorem (but will do so soon), but is it possible for example to paste the local solutions guaranteed by picard's theorem in a step by step manner to get a global solution ?

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over every subset $[-N,N]×\Bbb R^n$ of the domain you get a Lipschitz condition with constant
$$
L=\max_{t\in[-N,N]}\|A(t)\|,
$$
and with that a local solution over that interval.

By uniqueness, any solution can be extended to $\bigcup_{N\in\Bbb N}[-N,N]=\Bbb R$.